# PHPUnit Code Coverage

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, code-coverage

I am learning the ropes with Unit testing `Zend Framework` applications. So far I have set up `PHPUnit` to work with `Zend Framework` and have started writing some simple Test Cases.

My issue is that I am wondering why `Code Coverage` does not work in spite of being set in the logging tag in my `phpunit.xml`.

I don't get any error but no coverage report is generated.

However it works when I run `phpunit --coverage <dir>`

The logging section of my phpunit is as below:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./application/bootstrap.php" colors="true">
        <testsuite name="CI Test Suite">
            <directory>./</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Library Test Suite">
            <directory>./library</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <filter>
            <whitelist>
                <directory suffix=".php">../application/</directory>
                <exclude>
                    <directory suffix=".phtml">../application</directory>
                    <file>../application/Bootstrap.php</file>
                    <file>../application/controllers/ErrorController.php</file>
                </exclude>
            </whitelist>
           <logging>
               <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/report" charset="UTF-8" yui="true"
   highlight="true" lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80" />
               <log type="testdox" target="./log/testdox.html" />    
           </logging>
        </filter>
    </phpunit>
```

Anyone encounter this before? What is then likely problem?

Comment: I don't have my logging nested inside the filter.... that might make a bit of difference

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is the phpunit.xml for one of my projects, this works fine. As you can see, the logging section is outside the filter section, so that is probably your issue as commented by Mark Baker. I chose this one as it is from a small project and is very simple.

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php" colors="false">
    <testsuite name="HSSTests">
        <directory>./</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">d:/wamp/app_hss/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".phtml">d:/wamp/app_hss/</directory>
                <directory suffix=".php">d:/wamp/app_hss/tests/</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/codeCoverage" charset="UTF-8"
            yui="true" highlight="true"
            lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
        <log type="testdox-html" target="./log/testdox.html" />
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

All the information you could ever need on this is in the [PHPunit manual](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/appendixes.configuration.html).

Comment: You are absolutely right! The logging section should not have been within the filter section.