# PHPUnit warning - No filter is configured, code coverage will not be processed

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, warnings

I'm trying to generate coverage html file with PHPUnit. I get a warning: 'No filter is configured, code coverage will not be processed' and coverage file isn't generated.

This is phpunit.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" colors="true" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.3/phpunit.xsd">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
      <directory>./phpUnitTutorial</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could be worth having a look at some of the other questions about code coverage to see what they use - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284592/phpunit-code-coverage

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I suggest you use the configuration generator (`phpunit --generate-configuration`). It will ask you a couple of questions and then generate the right configuration for you.

Comment: Oh! That's real shame for me to admit that my coverage folder was created before asking question. I was looking for index.html file in root directory and I didn't notice that there was created new directory here. But thank You for your respond anyway. It's good to know this way, especially as I'm still beginner in PHPUnit.

Comment: Ok. After few tests (on generating coverage folder) I see that phpunit.xml needs not empty 'coverage' tag with specified valid source directory inside to generate coverage directory. Given solution generates this tag.

Comment: Doesn't _really_ answer the question though, does it? Which bit was missing? _That_ would have been the answer to the question. And then maybe a "hey did you know that if you use the configuration generator..." etc as a footnote.

Answer (score 19):

I added the following to my PHPUnit 9.5 configuration file between the `<phpunit>` tags:

```xml
<coverage>
    <include>
        <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
    </include>
</coverage>
```

Answer (score 7):

As of PHPUnit 10.x it is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<phpunit
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/10.1/phpunit.xsd"
        bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
        colors="true"
        beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
        cacheDirectory=".phpunit.cache"
        requireCoverageMetadata="true"
>
    ...
    <source>
        <include>
            <directory>../../src</directory>
        </include>
    </source>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 0):

for people like me: I had changed the namespace, but PHPStorm had moved everything in the src/ directory to the root directory of the project. The tests still run, but when trying to generate coverage, I got that message.